# Workbox service worker + manifest.json setup webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, service-worker, workbox-webpack-plugin

I’m trying to create a webpack builder with workbox, as i can see Vue CLI 3 is using.
In my package.json file, i’ve made a “build” to build and compile the files and a “dev” to run it.

```
"build": "webpack --mode development",
"dev": "nodemon --inspect --watch webpack.config.js main.js"
```

I use `InjectManifest` from `workbox-webpack-plugin` to handle the build in my `webpack.config.js` file. I've tryed different options to see what they did.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin')
const {GenerateSW, InjectManifest} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin')


module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        app: [
            '@babel/polyfill',
            './src/main.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: false,
        contentBase: "./dist",
        overlay: true,
        hot: true,
        stats: {
            colors: true
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'html-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader", options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader", options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html'
        }),
        // new GenerateSW({
        //     include: [/\.html$/, /\.js$/, /\.css$/],
        //     exclude: '/node_modules'
        // }),
        new InjectManifest({
            swSrc: './src/js/registerServiceWorker.js',
            swDest: '/serviceworker.js',
            exclude: '/node_modules'
          })
        // service worker caching
        // new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin(
        //     {
        //         cacheId: 'webpack-project',
        //         filename: 'service-worker.js',
        //         staticFileGlobs: [
        //             'dist/**/*.{js,css}',
        //             '/'
        //         ],
        //         minify: true,
        //         stripPrefix: 'dist/',
        //         dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{6}\./
        //     }
        // )
    ]
}
```

When i build the project, i creates the following files:

```
app-e8dd91....js
index.html
precache-manifest.d92js8....js
serviceworker.js
```

index.html file only adds the app-e8d91....js file as a script leaving the precached manifest file and service worker not being used, which results in that there's no service worker to my localhost.

I have a registerServiceWorker.js file which is being referenced in the injectManifest plugin.

**registerServiceWorker.js**

```
 import { register } from "register-service-worker";
const path = require('path')

register(path.resolve(__dirname, 'service-worker.js'), {
    ready() {
        console.log(
        "App is being served from cache by a service worker."
        );
    },
    cached() {
        console.log("Content has been cached for offline use.");
    },
    updated() {
        console.log("New content is available; please refresh.");
    },
    offline() {
        console.log(
        "No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode."
        );
    },
    error(error) {
        console.error("Error during service worker registration:", error);
    }
});
```

How do i make my build create and add the service worker + manifest.json file, so it works on localhost and also works offline?

**File structure:**

```
webpack.config.js
server.js (handle server + webpackHotMiddleware + express)
dist (builded folder)
src (folder)
     main.js
     js (folder)
         registerServiceWorker.js
public (folder)
    index.html
    manifest.json
    favicon.ico
```

Comment: to load the SW , index.html should load js that registers the SW. for input to injectManifest, run generateSW (one time only) to create the input to the inject step

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Robert Rowntree! If i run the generateSW in does the same with creating the files, but doesn't add the service worker and manifest to index.html. I shouldn't add the service worker and manifest to my index manually, right? If i add it, the path to the files wouldn't fit to when only the dist folder is being served.

Like. if i add <script src="./../src/js/registerServiceWorker.js this route doesn't exist when running dist folder. How do i both GenereateSW and InjectManifest?

Comment: "injectmanifest plugin"  section here : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin  uses 'sw.js'  .. IMO if you run webpack once to create the file 'sw.js'  then run webpack w the injectManifest u will get what u want.

Comment: Can you show me how? I don't quite get it

Comment: extra backgrnd in this thread : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1260   may help u

Comment: I still can't seem to figure out how to set it up properly according to this